# To use yarn in Visual Studio 2017 and Core 2.x, do I return to using package.json?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-2017, bower, yarnpkg

I wanted to use yarn in my ASP.NET Core 2.x Project in Visual Studio 2017.  Core doesn't support or doesn't install package.json, as was relayed by MS a while back.

Now, I find out Bower is being deprecated (though maintained...for now).  I thought I should use Yarn (and not npm proper supposedly.)  however, I found I need to bring package.json back to the project.

Is creating the package.json file in VS2017 going to return from Microsoft, as in the stock templates?  I read the documentation below and many comments, but I'm not sure how to proceed.  Will there be problems with a project if the package.json file exists?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bower

I have read this,

[Moving away from Bower (discontinued) to use Yarn/Npm instead (.Net Core MVC) VS2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844048/moving-away-from-bower-discontinued-to-use-yarn-npm-instead-net-core-mvc-vs)

And yes, I did add the package.json file with npm (Yarn uses npm repositories from what I read).  I am asking, however, if we are supposed to be returning to package.json, since it has been removed.

Comment: The `package.json` has been removed for NuGet packages. Those are stored in the `*.*proj` files now. Other package managers can use whatever dependency management file they want.

Comment: @jessehouwing you mean `packages.config`?

Comment: In Visual Studio 15.6 and up as well as .NET core, the packages.config is also deprecated. Nuget references are stored in the `<packageReference>` tags in the projects: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Comment: @jessehouwing right, but `packages.json` (NPM packages) have never been part of the .*proj.  (Common naming confusion)

Comment: Right and it looks like they never will. You can safely tuck them away in the `project.json`