# Using yarn to add a package removes existing modules

Tags: asp.net-core, yarnpkg

When I use Yarn in an ASP.NET Core 2.1 Web Application to add a package, e.g., `jquery-autocomplete`, it removes the existing packages already installed. Why is it doing that? Does it have something to do with `Popper.js`, which seems to be a dependency of the package I want to install when this happens?

At the command prompt in the project root I typed:

```
yarn add --modules-folder=wwwroot\lib autocomplete
```

Comment: Correction: at the command prompt I entered yarn add --modules-folder=wwwroot\lib jquery-autocomplete

Comment: What do you mean with "removes existing packages"? Does it remove them from your package.json or does it remove files in lib folder?

Comment: It removes all files from the lib folder.

Comment: Also, in the npm folder under Dependencies, the references to the files removed from the lib folder say "not installed,", e.g., bootstrap - not installed

Comment: Ok, I fear you have "some setup" that works differently as you think it works. You'll have to do some research. In most cases npm modules are stored in a folder "node_modules" that is outside your wwwroot. Then there's a wwwroot/lib folder with js libs but these are not managed using npm but with bower or LibManager https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/library-manager-libman-visual-studio-2017 .

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will check out Library Manager.  My understanding from this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44844048/moving-away-from-bower-discontinued-to-use-yarn-npm-instead-net-core-mvc-vs, was that yarn/npm was in, bower out.  Now it's LibMan?  This constant state of flux with the code makes it hard to get any work done.  Too many options, dribs and drabs of documentation, permanent state of Open Source chaos.

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but npm/yarn work differently and in most cases it requires some additional build setup (gulp/grunt/webpack). LibMan is a lightweight alternative for smaller projects and I think it better fits your requirements.

Comment: I appreciate your comments, but I would still like to know why using yarn to add a javaScript module removes existing files from the lib folder.

Comment: Where's you package.json placed and how does it look bevor and after you added the lib? Which folders are in your wwwroot/lib folder before and after?

Comment: The package.json file is located under the project directory, same level as appsettings.json, Start.cs, and Program.js.  When I use yarn to add a module, it appears as a line in package.json, otherwise the file is unchanged (the already existing files remain listed there).  But again, the problem I am trying to understand is why the existing modules are completely removed from the lib folder but seem to be cached by npm somewhere.  In ay case, the program is not able to find them.

Comment: I guess it's because npm/yarn has absolutely nothing to do with your lib folder. I think your existing lib folder content does not match the files in your package.json (because npm was not used to install them), right? Npm install is not a "copy this package to this location". Please read a little about npm, e.g. https://www.sitepoint.com/beginners-guide-node-package-manager/

Comment: Ok, I see, you're following the instructions in the linked question. 1) imho: don't. Reason: Many packages are not made to be placed in public. 2) Manage all packages in your lib folder with yarn or none - that should fix your problem.